# Priority of require for dependencies with similar names in nodejs

Tags: node.js, requirejs

Today I had a bug in a nodejs application, I found the root cause but I can't find a document specifying this behavior and my searches online didn't yield much results. So I am looking for a resource which would explicitly explain why this is happening. I think it is somewhere online but I miss the right keywords to find what I'm looking for.

To explain the situation let's say I have the following directory tree. Notice how there are three objects which can be imported as `config`:

```
.
├ config
│  └ index.js # Exports a simple object:   `module.exports = { file: "config/index.js" };`
├ config.js   # Exports a another object:  `module.exports = { file: "config.js" };`
├ config.json # Contains a different json: `{ "file": "config.json" }`
└ module
   └ index.js
```

Now in `module/index.js` if I `require` either of the three other files explicitly everything goes as expected:

```
console.log(require("../config.js"));       // { file: 'config.js' }
console.log(require("../config.json"));     // { file: 'config.json' }
console.log(require("../config/index.js")); // { file: 'config/index.js' }
```

The behavior which I need to explain is when I `require('../config')` without specifying the exact file. From my tests it seems that the priority is in this order:

- First try to import `config.js`
- Then try to import `config.json`
- And if none of the other exists try to import `config/index.js`

But I can't find any resource which would explicitly specify this behavior. I read [this nodejs doc](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html) but couldn't find specifications about this specific behavior. Where can I learn more about the priority order applied by `require` to similar modules names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules and priorities for `require()` are pretty well spelled out [here in the nodejs doc](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together).

That starts out with this:

```
require(X) from module at path Y
1. If X is a core module,
   a. return the core module
   b. STOP
2. If X begins with '/'
   a. set Y to be the filesystem root
3. If X begins with './' or '/' or '../'
   a. LOAD_AS_FILE(Y + X)
   b. LOAD_AS_DIRECTORY(Y + X)
   c. THROW "not found"
4. If X begins with '#'
   a. LOAD_PACKAGE_IMPORTS(X, dirname(Y))
5. LOAD_PACKAGE_SELF(X, dirname(Y))
6. LOAD_NODE_MODULES(X, dirname(Y))
7. THROW "not found"
```

Since neither steps 1 or 2 apply but 3 does apply, it will first try 3a with `LOAD_AS_FILE(Y + X)`.

And, `LOAD_AS_FILE` looks like this:

```
LOAD_AS_FILE(X)
1. If X is a file, load X as its file extension format. STOP
2. If X.js is a file, load X.js as JavaScript text. STOP
3. If X.json is a file, parse X.json to a JavaScript Object. STOP
4. If X.node is a file, load X.node as binary addon. STOP
```

From there, you can see your observed priority of looking for `config.js` first, then `config.json`.

And only if these two fail does it then move onto step 3b `LOAD_AS_DIRECORY(Y+X)` where it would find the `index.js`.

Comment: That’s exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!